# Convert Rtsp Packet to bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, rtsp, rtsp-client

Hello Every on I have implemented SharpRtsp in c# https://github.com/ngraziano/SharpRTSP
I am receiving rtsp Packets and it has h264 format It has following method in H264Payload Class

```
private List<byte[]> Process_H264_RTP_Frame(List<byte[]> rtp_payloads)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RTP Data comprised of " + rtp_payloads.Count + " rtp packets");

            List<byte[]> nal_units = new List<byte[]>(); // Stores the NAL units for a Video Frame. May be more than one NAL unit in a video frame.

            for (int payload_index = 0; payload_index < rtp_payloads.Count; payload_index++)
            {
                // Examine the first rtp_payload and the first byte (the NAL header)
                int nal_header_f_bit = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][0] >> 7) & 0x01;
                int nal_header_nri = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][0] >> 5) & 0x03;
                int nal_header_type = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][0] >> 0) & 0x1F;

                // If the Nal Header Type is in the range 1..23 this is a normal NAL (not fragmented)
                // So write the NAL to the file
                if (nal_header_type >= 1 && nal_header_type <= 23)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Normal NAL");
                    norm++;
                    nal_units.Add(rtp_payloads[payload_index]);
                }
                // There are 4 types of Aggregation Packet (split over RTP payloads)
                else if (nal_header_type == 24)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Agg STAP-A");
                    stap_a++;

                    // RTP packet contains multiple NALs, each with a 16 bit header
                    //   Read 16 byte size
                    //   Read NAL
                    try
                    {
                        int ptr = 1; // start after the nal_header_type which was '24'
                        // if we have at least 2 more bytes (the 16 bit size) then consume more data
                        while (ptr + 2 < (rtp_payloads[payload_index].Length - 1))
                        {
                            int size = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][ptr] << 8) + (rtp_payloads[payload_index][ptr + 1] << 0);
                            ptr = ptr + 2;
                            byte[] nal = new byte[size];
                            System.Array.Copy(rtp_payloads[payload_index], ptr, nal, 0, size); // copy the NAL
                            nal_units.Add(nal); // Add to list of NALs for this RTP frame. Start Codes like 00 00 00 01 get added later
                            ptr = ptr + size;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
                else if (nal_header_type == 25)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Agg STAP-B not supported");
                    stap_b++;
                }
                else if (nal_header_type == 26)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Agg MTAP16 not supported");
                    mtap16++;
                }
                else if (nal_header_type == 27)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Agg MTAP24 not supported");
                    mtap24++;
                }
                else if (nal_header_type == 28)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Frag FU-A");
                    fu_a++;

                    // Parse Fragmentation Unit Header
                    int fu_header_s = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][1] >> 7) & 0x01;  // start marker
                    int fu_header_e = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][1] >> 6) & 0x01;  // end marker
                    int fu_header_r = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][1] >> 5) & 0x01;  // reserved. should be 0
                    int fu_header_type = (rtp_payloads[payload_index][1] >> 0) & 0x1F; // Original NAL unit header

                    Console.WriteLine("Frag FU-A s=" + fu_header_s + "e=" + fu_header_e);

                    // Check Start and End flags
                    if (fu_header_s == 1 && fu_header_e == 0)
                    {
                        // Start of Fragment.
                        // Initiise the fragmented_nal byte array
                        // Build the NAL header with the original F and NRI flags but use the the Type field from the fu_header_type
                        byte reconstructed_nal_type = (byte)((nal_header_f_bit << 7) + (nal_header_nri << 5) + fu_header_type);

                        // Empty the stream
                        fragmented_nal.SetLength(0);

                        // Add reconstructed_nal_type byte to the memory stream
                        fragmented_nal.WriteByte(reconstructed_nal_type);

                        // copy the rest of the RTP payload to the memory stream
                        fragmented_nal.Write(rtp_payloads[payload_index], 2, rtp_payloads[payload_index].Length - 2);
                    }

                    if (fu_header_s == 0 && fu_header_e == 0)
                    {
                        // Middle part of Fragment
                        // Append this payload to the fragmented_nal
                        // Data starts after the NAL Unit Type byte and the FU Header byte
                        fragmented_nal.Write(rtp_payloads[payload_index], 2, rtp_payloads[payload_index].Length - 2);
                    }

                    if (fu_header_s == 0 && fu_header_e == 1)
                    {
                        // End part of Fragment
                        // Append this payload to the fragmented_nal
                        // Data starts after the NAL Unit Type byte and the FU Header byte
                        fragmented_nal.Write(rtp_payloads[payload_index], 2, rtp_payloads[payload_index].Length - 2);

                        // Add the NAL to the array of NAL units
                        nal_units.Add(fragmented_nal.ToArray());
                    }
                }

                else if (nal_header_type == 29)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Frag FU-B not supported");
                    fu_b++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unknown NAL header " + nal_header_type + " not supported");
                }

            }

            // Output some statistics
            Console.WriteLine("Norm=" + norm + " ST-A=" + stap_a + " ST-B=" + stap_b + " M16=" + mtap16 + " M24=" + mtap24 + " FU-A=" + fu_a + " FU-B=" + fu_b);

            // Output all the NALs that form one RTP Frame (one frame of video)
            return nal_units;

        }


    }
```

I have triew and done reading but i have not found any way to convert H264 Frame into bitmap I just want it to save as bitmaps can any body help me o convert this data to bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

The end of that function returns data in H264 format

> ```
>         // Output all the NALs that form one RTP Frame (one frame of video)
>         return nal_units;
> ```

To get a bitmap you need to pass the H264 data into a Video Decompressor. If you are not familiar with digital video, then think about .ZIP or .RAR or .7Z files.
You cannot read the contents of these files without the right software to convert the compressed data back to a usable format.
The same applies to video. H264 is a compressed data format.
You need to use a H264 decompression codec to confer the nal_units into a bitmap (or another video format called YUV).

Some people use ffmpeg for this decompression. Others pass the H264 data into an Operating System API (like VideoToolbox on the Mac or MediaCodec on Android or whatever Windows supports).

But you need these extra steps.